# "Which type of client-side component to create?" is missing "Extension"

Tags: yeoman, spfx, yeoman-generator, yo

I am using Node.js 14.18.1 (x64) and npm.

When i run `D:\extensionfullstack>yo @microsoft/sharepoint` I got this :-

```
D:\>cd D:\extensionfullstack

D:\extensionfullstack>yo @microsoft/sharepoint

     _-----_     ╭──────────────────────────╮
    |       |    │      Welcome to the      │
    |--(o)--|    │  SharePoint Client-side  │
   `---------´   │         Solution         │
    ( _´U`_ )    │     Generator@1.13.0     │
    /___A___\   /╰──────────────────────────╯
     |  ~  |
   __'.___.'__
 ´   `  |° ´ Y `

Let's create a new SharePoint solution.
? What is your solution name? extensionfullstack
? Only SharePoint Online (latest) is supported.  For earlier versions of SharePoint (2016 and 2019) please use the 1.4.1
 version of the generator. SharePoint Online only (latest)
? Where do you want to place the files? Use the current folder
? Do you want to allow the tenant admin the choice of being able to deploy the solution to all sites immediately without
 running any feature deployment or adding apps in sites? Yes
? Will the components in the solution require permissions to access web APIs that are unique and not shared with other c
omponents in the tenant? Yes
? Which type of client-side component to create?
> WebPart
```

Where "Extension" option is missing any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have selected "Yes" for the option "Will the components in the solution require permissions to access web APIs that are unique and not shared with other components in the tenant?" Yes.

This is "[isolated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/isolated-web-parts)" option.

The answer you selected is not compatible with "Extension", only "WebPart". You could answer "No" to this question to be able to select "Extension", or use a later version of the generator (1.14) that does not ask this question.

Comment: While I believe @Nikolay's answer is correct, the following documentation may also prove to be a helpful reference  for handling configurations on newer versions where the prompts aren't present - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/yeoman-generator-for-spfx-intro#retired-generator-prompts